# I'm getting a reference error, "cannot access 'member' before initialization"

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

When I run the code and proceed to do the command "-kick @user", I get an error in the console saying "Cannot access 'member' before initialization". I don't get what it means by that.. The code I'm trying to run is this one..

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();
const token = '-----'

const PREFIX = '-';

Client.login(token);


Client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'kick':
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send('You need to specify a person !')

            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = member.guild.member(user);

                if (member) {
                    member.kick('You have been kicked !').then(() => {
                        message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        message.reply('I was unable to kick the member')
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    message.reply("That user isn't in the guild")
                }
            } else {
                message.reply('That user isn't in the guild');
            }


            break;
    }
})
```
````

Comment: With `const member = member.guild.member(user);` what are you intending the `member` part of `member.guild` to refer to? Did you mean `user`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want it to refer to the another user. Also, I did change it to `user.guild.member(user); but now when I try running it, it now says "cannot read property 'member' of undefined" So I'm pretty much confused at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a mistake of inattention, you have to replace this line:

```js
const member = member.guild.member(user);
```

by this:

```js
const member = message.guild.member(user);
```